# PHP Email Send Swift

Tags: php, swiftmailer

SWIFT EMAIL ERROR

I have swift set up to send emails but have come accross a problem concerning an email address that it cannot send to despite the fact that it exists.

In my create message section I set the address:

```
$message->addTo('johnx@gmail.com');
```

When this runs - its fine and sends the mail

When I set the email to:

```
$message->addTo('johnx@my3company.com');
```

It fails for ANY address to that domain - not sure why?

Any Ideas please

Comment: what means "fail" did you receive error or something other?

Comment: Well, that domain doesn't exist, which may be the problem...

Comment: ok someone had to check - the domain is gf3data.com and the email below in the error meesage exists

Failures:Array ( [0] => accounts@gf3data.com ) Failures:Array ( [0] => accounts@gf3data.com [1] => accounts@gf3data.com )

Comment: OK - I realise something the domain I'm sending to is also the domain its sending FROM.
Is that an issue with Swift